# Manufacturer in product url key

Tags: url-rewrite, magento-1.9, product-urls

I am trying to have all product url keys automatically generated this way:

site.com/manufacturer-productname-sku.html

I managed to add the SKU adding to the file /app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Urlkey.php:

```
public function beforeSave($object)
    {
        $attributeName = $this->getAttribute()->getName();

        $urlKey = $object->getData($attributeName);
        if ($urlKey === false) {
            return $this;
        }
        if ($urlKey == '') {
            $urlKey = $object->getName().'-'.$object->getSku();
        }


      $object->setData($attributeName, $object->formatUrlKey($urlKey));

        return $this;
    }
```

Adding `getManufacturer()` or `getData('manufacturer')` are not working, so the `$_product->getAttributeText`

Any suggestion?

It would also be better if the SKU kept the capital letters, but that's an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using  catalog_product_save_befoe event .Here
 details below

code `MageStack_24869.xml`  of app\etc\modules\

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
    <MageStack_24869>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <active>true</active>
    </MageStack_24869>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And `config.xml` path `app\code\local\MageStack\24869\etc\`
and code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MageStack_24869>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </MageStack_24869>
  </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mageStack24869>
                <class>MageStack_24869_Model</class>
            </mageStack24869>
        </models>
  </global>
    <global>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <mageStack24869>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>mageStack24869/observer</class>
                        <method>updateurl</method>
                    </mageStack24869>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_before>
        </events>
    </global>       
</config>
```

Also `Observer.php` code path (`app\code\local\MageStack\24869\Model`)

```
<?php
class MageStack_24869_Model_Observer{
    public function updateurl($observer){
        //Mage::log('My log entry', null, 'mylogfile.log');
        if($observer->getEvent()->getProduct()){
            $Product=$observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
            $Url='';
            if(!is_null($Product->getData('country_of_manufacture'))):
            $Url=$Url.$Product->getAttributeText('country_of_manufacture').'-';
            endif;
            if(!is_null($Product->getData('sku'))):
            $Url=$Url.$Product->getData('sku').'-';
            endif;
            if(!is_null($Product->getData('name'))):
            $Url=$Url.$Product->getData('name');
            endif;
            //Mage::log('My log entry'.$Url, null, 'mylogfile.log');
            $Product->setData('url_key',$Url);      

        }
    }
}
```

Also you can do using below code

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987445/how-to-customize-product-url

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I only had to edit `country_of_manufacture` with `manufacturer`