# Add a static URL prefix for product and category Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-urls, url-key

I need to specify a prefix static string for all URLs of my Products and Categories. Just like Wordpress Woocommerce permalinks.

For example all of Categories should have `product-category` prefix in their URL:

- Cat One: `domain.com/product-category/cat-one`
- Cat Two (child of 'Cat One'): `domain.com/product-category/cat-one/cat-two`

and all of Products should have `product` URL prefix, no matter what their Category is:

- Product One: `domain.com/product/product-one`
- Product Two: `domain.com/product/product-two`

I tried to do [this solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25049/static-product-url-prefix), but It's for 3 years ago and not working in Magento 2.

Also [this extension](https://extensions.activo.com/seo-friendly-categories-for-magento.html) is for Magento 1.x as you see.

By the way, I'm using **Magento 2.1.9 with PHP 7.0.22 and XAMPP 3.2.2**.

Thanks.

Comment: Seriously... it has not any solution! oh come on ...

Comment: Have you find solution for this ?

Comment: @ManthanDave Yes, I answered it down.

Comment: Yes i have already done that on same day- here is the link - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206855/magento-2-2-how-to-add-static-product-prefix-to-product-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a good solution for this situation!

We need to make our custom module for **extending** `Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator` class with plugin methods and `Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator` class with preference class (because we need to change inside of its methods, not change after or before them).

Assume that our **custom module** created by this [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/build.html), has `<Vendor>` and `<Module>` names.

> 1) So, at first we need to define our **plugin** and **preference** class in our [`etc/di.xml` file](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator" type="<Vendor>\<Module>\Model\CatalogUrlRewrite\ProductUrlPathGenerator"/>

    <type name="Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator">
      <plugin name="my_category_url_path_generator" type="<Vendor>\<Module>\Plugin\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator" sortOrder="15"/>
    </type>

  </config>
```

> 2) Add these classes in proper addresses:
>
> > a) Our preference class in `<Vendor>\<Module>\Model\CatalogUrlRewrite\ProductUrlPathGenerator.php` :
> >
> > **--> Change this two constant in this class for your own custom static route: <--**

```
<?php
    namespace <Vendor>\<Module>\Model\CatalogUrlRewrite;

    class ProductUrlPathGenerator extends \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator
    {

        // CHANGE THESE FOR CUSTOM STATIC PREFIX ROUTE of PRODUCT and PRODUCT CATEGORY
        const PRODUCT_PREFIX_ROUTE = 'product';
        const CATEGORY_PREFIX_ROUTE = 'product-category';

        /**
         * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
         * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
         * @param \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator $categoryUrlPathGenerator
         * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
            \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator $categoryUrlPathGenerator,
            \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
        ) {
            parent::__construct($storeManager, $scopeConfig, $categoryUrlPathGenerator, $productRepository);
        }

        /**
         * Retrieve Product Url path (with category if exists)
         *
         * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
         * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getUrlPath($product, $category = null)
        {
            $path = $product->getData('url_path');
            if ($path === null) {
                $path = $product->getUrlKey()
                    ? $this->prepareProductUrlKey($product)
                    : $this->prepareProductDefaultUrlKey($product);
            }

            if ($category !== null) {
                $categoryUrl = str_replace(self::CATEGORY_PREFIX_ROUTE .'/','',$this->categoryUrlPathGenerator->getUrlPath($category));
                $path = $categoryUrl . '/' . $path;
            }

            return self::PRODUCT_PREFIX_ROUTE . '/' . $path;
        }
    }
```

> > b ) Our plugin class in `<Vendor>\<Module>\Plugin\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator.php` :

```
<?php
namespace <Vendor>\<Module>\Plugin\Model;


class CategoryUrlPathGenerator
{
    /**
    * Add a static prefix to category URL path
    *
    * @param \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator $subject
    * @param $path
    * @return string
    */
    public function afterGetUrlPath(\Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator $subject, $path)
    {
        if (strpos($path, \<Vendor>\<Module>\Model\CatalogUrlRewrite\ProductUrlPathGenerator::CATEGORY_PREFIX_ROUTE) === false)
            $path = \<Vendor>\<Module>\Model\CatalogUrlRewrite\ProductUrlPathGenerator::CATEGORY_PREFIX_ROUTE . $path;

        return $path;
    }
}
```

> 3) Run this command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

And its **DONE!**, now you can create products and their categories and you'll see the url rewrites that created with these static url prefixes.

> **DO NOT forget to change `<Vendor>`,`<Module>` with your own custom module names and change the constants of `ProductUrlPathGenerator` class for change to your custom static prefixes.**

Good luck.

Comment: Hello @Mehran. Can you please let me know why you have used strpos with prefix and path in CategoryUrlPathGenerator plugin? I am not getting it. Otherwise, this solution works fine.

Comment: strpos is used to check if the url_path already has the prefix in it and stops it being added when it is already present.