# Magento 2 .2 - How to add Static Product Prefix to Product Url?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, magento2.2

**I would like to add a Product Prefix (Static Path) to product URLs.**

Something like **www.test.com/product-prefix/product1.html**

So all products url of the website follows the same structure - **www.test.com/product-prefix/product2.html**

Where **product-prefix** is a **static product-prefix.**

**I want to add it as statically , no url rewrite concept.**

I have checked core **ProductUrlPathGenerator.php** but not getting exact solution. Can anybody help and suggest the better way ?

**Magento Version - 2.2**

Comment: Thanks for your solution I did the same way but its not working for me I am using magento 2.2.6 version. Can you please help me on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After debugging of couple of hours i have resolved this issue by following below method.

**I have override two files in my custom module, One is Product Url Model and Another one is Router Controller\Router**

**Below is the di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Url" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Url" />
<preference for="Magento\UrlRewrite\Controller\Router" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Router" />
```

**Code for Url.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * Product Url model
 *
 * @author     Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite;

class Url extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Url
{
    /**
     * URL instance
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlFactory
     */
    protected $urlFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager
     */
    protected $filter;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolverInterface
     */
    protected $sidResolver;

    /** @var UrlFinderInterface */
    protected $urlFinder;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlFactory $urlFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager $filter
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolverInterface $sidResolver
     * @param UrlFinderInterface $urlFinder
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\UrlFactory $urlFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager $filter,
        \Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolverInterface $sidResolver,
        UrlFinderInterface $urlFinder,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($urlFactory, $storeManager, $filter, $sidResolver, $urlFinder, $data);
        $this->urlFactory = $urlFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->sidResolver = $sidResolver;
        $this->urlFinder = $urlFinder;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve URL Instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    private function getUrlInstance()
    {
        return $this->urlFactory->create();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve URL in current store
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @param array $params the URL route params
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrlInStore(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, $params = [])
    {
        $params['_scope_to_url'] = true;
        return $this->getUrl($product, $params);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Product URL
     *
     * @param  \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @param  bool $useSid forced SID mode
     * @return string
     */
    public function getProductUrl($product, $useSid = null)
    {
        if ($useSid === null) {
            $useSid = $this->sidResolver->getUseSessionInUrl();
        }

        $params = [];
        if (!$useSid) {
            $params['_nosid'] = true;
        }

        return $this->getUrl($product, $params);
    }

    /**
     * Format Key for URL
     *
     * @param string $str
     * @return string
     */
    public function formatUrlKey($str)
    {
        return $this->filter->translitUrl($str);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Product URL using UrlDataObject
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @param array $params
     * @return string
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function getUrl(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, $params = [])
    {
        $routePath = '';
        $routeParams = $params;

        $storeId = $product->getStoreId();

        $categoryId = null;

        if (!isset($params['_ignore_category']) && $product->getCategoryId() && !$product->getDoNotUseCategoryId()) {
            $categoryId = $product->getCategoryId();
        }

        if ($product->hasUrlDataObject()) {
            $requestPath = $product->getUrlDataObject()->getUrlRewrite();
            $routeParams['_scope'] = $product->getUrlDataObject()->getStoreId();
        } else {
            $requestPath = $product->getRequestPath();
            if (empty($requestPath) && $requestPath !== false) {
                $filterData = [
                    UrlRewrite::ENTITY_ID => $product->getId(),
                    UrlRewrite::ENTITY_TYPE => \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlRewriteGenerator::ENTITY_TYPE,
                    UrlRewrite::STORE_ID => $storeId,
                ];
                if ($categoryId) {
                    $filterData[UrlRewrite::METADATA]['category_id'] = $categoryId;
                }
                $rewrite = $this->urlFinder->findOneByData($filterData);
                if ($rewrite) {
                    $requestPath = $rewrite->getRequestPath();
                    $product->setRequestPath($requestPath);
                } else {
                    $product->setRequestPath(false);
                }
            }
        }

        if (isset($routeParams['_scope'])) {
            $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore($routeParams['_scope'])->getId();
        }

        if ($storeId != $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()) {
            $routeParams['_scope_to_url'] = true;
        }

        if (!empty($requestPath)) {
            $routeParams['_direct'] = $requestPath;
        } else {
            $routePath = 'catalog/product/view';
            $routeParams['id'] = $product->getId();
            $routeParams['s'] = $product->getUrlKey();
            if ($categoryId) {
                $routeParams['category'] = $categoryId;
            }
        }

        // reset cached URL instance GET query params
        if (!isset($routeParams['_query'])) {
            $routeParams['_query'] = [];
        }
$baseUrl = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
        $productUrl = $this->getUrlInstance()->setScope($storeId)->getUrl($routePath, $routeParams);

        $remainingUrl = str_replace($baseUrl, '', $productUrl);

        $productUrl = $baseUrl."your-static-prefix/" . $remainingUrl;
        //return $this->getUrlInstance()->setScope($storeId)->getUrl($routePath, $routeParams);
        return $productUrl;
    }
}
```

**Code for Controller Router.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Controller;

use Magento\UrlRewrite\Controller\Adminhtml\Url\Rewrite;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\OptionProvider;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite;

/**
 * UrlRewrite Controller Router
 */
class Router implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
{
    /** var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory */
    protected $actionFactory;

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface */
    protected $url;

    /** @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface */
    protected $storeManager;

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface */
    protected $response;

    /** @var UrlFinderInterface */
    protected $urlFinder;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response
     * @param UrlFinderInterface $urlFinder
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response,
        UrlFinderInterface $urlFinder
    ) {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->response = $response;
        $this->urlFinder = $urlFinder;
    }

    /**
     * Match corresponding URL Rewrite and modify request
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface|null
     */
    public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        if ($fromStore = $request->getParam('___from_store')) {
            $oldStoreId = $this->storeManager->getStore($fromStore)->getId();
            $oldRewrite = $this->getRewrite($request->getPathInfo(), $oldStoreId);
            if ($oldRewrite) {
                $rewrite = $this->urlFinder->findOneByData(
                    [
                        UrlRewrite::ENTITY_TYPE => $oldRewrite->getEntityType(),
                        UrlRewrite::ENTITY_ID => $oldRewrite->getEntityId(),
                        UrlRewrite::STORE_ID => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
                        UrlRewrite::IS_AUTOGENERATED => 1,
                    ]
                );
                if ($rewrite && $rewrite->getRequestPath() !== $oldRewrite->getRequestPath()) {
                    return $this->redirect($request, $rewrite->getRequestPath(), OptionProvider::TEMPORARY);
                }
            }
        }
        //Below i have replaced static prefix

        $replaceUrl = str_replace("your-static-prefix/", "", $request->getPathInfo());
        $rewrite = $this->getRewrite($replaceUrl, $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());

        //$rewrite = $this->getRewrite($request->getPathInfo(), $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());

        // CODE FOR CATEGORY REWRITE
        if ($rewrite === null) 
        {
            $pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();
            $pathInfoArray = explode("/", $pathInfo);

            $key = "";
            if(!empty(trim($pathInfoArray[count($pathInfoArray) - 1])))
                $key = trim($pathInfoArray[count($pathInfoArray) - 1]);
            elseif(!empty(trim($pathInfoArray[count($pathInfoArray) - 2])))
                $key = trim($pathInfoArray[count($pathInfoArray) - 2]);

            if($key != "")
            {
                $objectManaer = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $category = $objectManaer->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category');
                $collection = $category->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('url_key', ['like' => '%' . $key . '%']);

                if($collection->count())
                {
                    $category = $collection->getFirstItem();
                    $path = $category->getPath();
                    $pathArray = explode("/", $category->getPath());

                    foreach(['1', '2', $category->getId()] as $del_val)
                    {
                        if (($categoryId = array_search($del_val, $pathArray)) !== false) {
                            unset($pathArray[$categoryId]);
                        }
                    }

                    $keyArray = [];
                    if(count($pathArray))
                    {
                        foreach($pathArray as $pathId)
                        {
                            $pathCategory = $objectManaer->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($pathId);
                            $keyArray[] = $pathCategory->getUrlKey();
                        }
                    }

                    $keyArray[] = $category->getUrlKey();
                    $key = implode("/", $keyArray);
                    $key = '/' . $key;
                    $rewrite = $this->getRewrite($key, $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
                }
            }
        }

        if ($rewrite === null) {
            return null;
        }

        if ($rewrite->getRedirectType()) {
            return $this->processRedirect($request, $rewrite);
        }

        $request->setAlias(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS, $rewrite->getRequestPath());
        $request->setPathInfo('/' . $rewrite->getTargetPath());
        return $this->actionFactory->create('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward');
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @param UrlRewrite $rewrite
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface|null
     */
    protected function processRedirect($request, $rewrite)
    {
        $target = $rewrite->getTargetPath();
        if ($rewrite->getEntityType() !== Rewrite::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOM
            || ($prefix = substr($target, 0, 6)) !== 'http:/' && $prefix !== 'https:'
        ) {
            $target = $this->url->getUrl('', ['_direct' => $target]);
        }
        return $this->redirect($request, $target, $rewrite->getRedirectType());
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @param string $url
     * @param int $code
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface
     */
    protected function redirect($request, $url, $code)
    {
        $this->response->setRedirect($url, $code);
        $request->setDispatched(true);
        return $this->actionFactory->create('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Redirect');
    }

    /**
     * @param string $requestPath
     * @param int $storeId
     * @return UrlRewrite|null
     */
    protected function getRewrite($requestPath, $storeId)
    {
        return $this->urlFinder->findOneByData([
            UrlRewrite::REQUEST_PATH => trim($requestPath, '/'),
            UrlRewrite::STORE_ID => $storeId,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very good.

Comment: @Manthan - will your solution work, if i want to add a custom attribute value (let's say, "brand") as prefix to product url ?

Comment: @ManashviBirla - Yes , it might work - have you tried the same

Comment: @ManthanDave: Thanks for writing the detailed solution.
What would you suggest if we want to add a static-path only for some products.

Comment: Also do you find this feasible inuff  to add a static path for a product only from one place. I mean is it possible in any way that a product have two URLs one the default as it is and another with the static-path (i know this is not feasible but its my requirement).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the same result but much less verbose and without rewriting the whole model using plugin.

Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" />
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Url">
        <plugin name="VendorProductUrl" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\UrlPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Vendor/Module/Plugin/UrlPlugin.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface as StoreManager;

class UrlPlugin
{

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var StoreManager
     */
     protected $_storeManager;

     public function __construct(
         StoreManager $_storeManager
     )
     {
        $this->_storeManager = $_storeManager;
     }

     /**
      * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Url $subject
      * @param string $url
      * @return string
      */
     public function afterGetUrl(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Url $subject, $url)
     {

         $baseUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
         return str_replace($baseUrl, $baseUrl."product-prefix/", $url);
     }
}
```