# Magento 2 - add prefix before category and products urls

Tags: magento2, url, product-urls, url-key

I want to add `prefix in category and product urls` of `Magneto 2.3.4`.

I was able to add prefix in product `urls` but not working on category `urls`.

Please guide.

Answer (score 3):

Please check below ways which are working solution to add a prefix before the category and products URLs

https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-add-prefix-to-store-products-urls-in-magento-2/

[Magento 2 .2 - How to add Static Product Prefix to Product Url?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206855/magento-2-2-how-to-add-static-product-prefix-to-product-url)

Check it out you will get the idea and let me know if you still need any help.

Thank You

Comment: This is only for product url prefix. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

[Add a static URL prefix for product and category Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195929/add-a-static-url-prefix-for-product-and-category-magento-2)

It worked fine. After the fix I rewrite all url via olegkoval extension