# Add static prefix to the product and category url

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.2, magento2.3.3

I have followed this tutorial [Add a static URL prefix for product and category Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195929/add-a-static-url-prefix-for-product-and-category-magento-2)

to create custom prefix for my store but i dont know why this is not working in my case

I am sharing all the details here :

**etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator" type="Demo\Mod\Model\CatalogUrlRewrite\ProductUrlPathGenerator"/>

    <type name="Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator">
      <plugin name="my_category_url_path_generator" type="Demo\Mod\Plugin\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator" sortOrder="15"/>
    </type>

  </config>
```

**/Model/Model\CatalogUrlRewrite\ProductUrlPathGenerator.php**

```
<?php
    namespace Demo\Mod\Model\CatalogUrlRewrite;

    class ProductUrlPathGenerator extends \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator
    {

        // CHANGE THESE FOR CUSTOM STATIC PREFIX ROUTE of PRODUCT and PRODUCT CATEGORY
        const PRODUCT_PREFIX_ROUTE = 'product';
        const CATEGORY_PREFIX_ROUTE = 'product-category';
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
            \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator $categoryUrlPathGenerator,
            \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
        ) {
            parent::__construct($storeManager, $scopeConfig, $categoryUrlPathGenerator, $productRepository);
        }

        public function getUrlPath($product, $category = null)
        {
            $path = $product->getData('url_path');
            if ($path === null) {
                $path = $product->getUrlKey()
                    ? $this->prepareProductUrlKey($product)
                    : $this->prepareProductDefaultUrlKey($product);
            }

            if ($category !== null) {
                $categoryUrl = str_replace(self::CATEGORY_PREFIX_ROUTE .'/','',$this->categoryUrlPathGenerator->getUrlPath($category));
                $path = $categoryUrl . '/' . $path;
            }

            return self::PRODUCT_PREFIX_ROUTE . '/' . $path;
        }
    }
```

**\Plugin\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator.php**

```
<?php
namespace Demo\Mod\Plugin\Model;


class CategoryUrlPathGenerator
{

    public function afterGetUrlPath(\Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator $subject, $path)
    {
        if (strpos($path, \Demo\Mod\Model\CatalogUrlRewrite\ProductUrlPathGenerator::CATEGORY_PREFIX_ROUTE) === false)
            $path = \Demo\Mod\Model\CatalogUrlRewrite\ProductUrlPathGenerator::CATEGORY_PREFIX_ROUTE . $path;

        return $path;
    }
}
```

also i want to remove `.html` from url end.
can i get some help here thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove .html from product url by following steps:

1. Login to admin
2. Goto Stores -> Configuration
3. Then Navigate to Catalog -> Catalog
4. Now move to Search Engine Optimization section
5. Remove the .html from Product URL Suffix
6. Save Config and Flush the cache

You can also do the same thing for Category url suffix as well. You can find the option there as well.

**Updated Answer for Category and Product Url prefix:**

You need regenerate the urls again for your website. You can do it by installing below module:
https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites

You can follow the above guidelines after installation of the module.

If still not work then delete the urls for category and products by running following commands on your database.

```
Delete * FROM `url_rewrite` WHERE `entity_type` LIKE '%category%';
Delete * FROM `url_rewrite` WHERE `entity_type` LIKE '%product%';
```

Then run the commands for url regeneration of the above module.

Thanks

Comment: but am not able to change url static prefix can you explain me how can i change this

Comment: Wait I am updating my answer.

Comment: okay thank you am getting a tough time to understand this code since am a beginner in magento

Comment: are you able to add static prefix in categories url?