# Does updating URL keys for products keep the original URL in rewrites?

Tags: url-rewrite, seo

I would like to update all my product URL keys because they are an absolute mess (and hoping to boost SEO).

Found a solution to recreate the URL keys  as Manufacturer / Product Name / SKU [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24869/manufacturer-in-product-url-key)

My question is: **When recreating URL keys for products, do the old URL's stay in URL Rewrites?**

My concern is that if the URL's are not preserved, that search engines would no longer be finding the products page and thus remove them from index (and having to wait until they are re-crawled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the old urls stay in the system they are just rewritten.

You need to understand the working of magento url rewrites here.
When you create a rewrite it creates a new url based on the old url so technically it has to store the old urls in the system to be able to create a new rewrite for it.

Comment: I understand that if I update the url keys manually, they are preserved. I'm trying to clarify if by implementing the example module (or any for that matter) that over rides the default magento functionality in writing URL's that the old ones will be preserved.

Comment: Yes it will preserve the old URLs for you.