# Recreating URL keys

Tags: url-rewrite, seo

I'm trying to recreate URL keys for all my products to include the product name and then the SKU. I found [this helpful post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24869/manufacturer-in-product-url-key) that claims to resolve the issue, however I just can't seem to get it to work.

The main difference is that I do not want to include the manufacturer name (most of my products have this in the product name) and I've changed the order in which the link is generated (*www.mysite.com/product_name-SKU*):

```
<?php
class MageStack_24869_Model_Observer{
public function updateurl($observer){
    //Mage::log('My log entry', null, 'mylogfile.log');
    if($observer->getEvent()->getProduct()){
        $Product=$observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $Url='';
       // if(!is_null($Product->getData('country_of_manufacture'))):
       // $Url=$Url.$Product->getAttributeText('country_of_manufacture').'-';
       // endif;
        if(!is_null($Product->getData('name'))):
        $Url=$Url.$Product->getData('name').'-';
        endif;
        if(!is_null($Product->getData('sku'))):
        $Url=$Url.$Product->getData('sku');
        endif;
        Mage::log('My log entry'.$Url, null, 'mylogfile.log');
        $Product->setData('url_key',$Url);      

    }
}
}
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<MageStack_24869>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
  </MageStack_24869>
  </modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <mageStack24869>
            <class>MageStack_24869_Model</class>
</mageStack24869>
</models>
  </global>
   <global>
      <events>
        <catalog_product_save_before>
            <observers>
                <mageStack24869>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>mageStack24869/observer</class>
                    <method>updateurl</method>
                </mageStack24869>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before>
    </events>
</global>       
</config>
```

The only thing I can think of is that there is a reference to the url being "null" - so I don't know if because I already have url keys that they are not updated.

**Is there something wrong with the above logic and/or solution to rewrite all url keys?**

Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of `Mage::log('My log entry'.$Url, null, 'mylogfile.log');`? Is your config the same as the example you link to?

Comment: Good question, actually the log file is never generated. (Yes I have uncommented the top section as well.)

Comment: Is the observer getting executed?

Comment: can you add your config.xml? What happen when you save a product from admin?

Comment: updated with config.xml - when I open a product in the admin panel and hit "save" it then updates the key. So now I just need it to update when I re-index all unless this isn't the correct way to do it?

Comment: So it seem like it working, you just need to reindex? also you should delete the double `global` tag see `</models>
  </global>
   <global>`

Comment: Like I said - I've re-indexed and there were no changes. Only when I tried your suggestion to save a product in the admin panel did it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code below you will manually have to re-save all existing products for the url to change (`catalog_product_save_before` only executed when that product is save/created).

You can either resave all existing product manually to update there existing url or create a one time script to update all existing products and then this script will take care of future add or update products.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MageStack_24869>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </MageStack_24869>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
        <mageStack24869>
            <class>MageStack_24869_Model</class>
        </mageStack24869>
    </models>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_before>
            <observers>
                <mageStack24869>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>mageStack24869/observer</class>
                    <method>updateurl</method>
                </mageStack24869>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before>
    </events>
  </global>       
</config>
```

Observer.php

```
class MageStack_24869_Model_Observer{
  public function updateurl($observer){
    //Mage::log('My log entry', null, 'mylogfile.log');
    $Product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()
    if($Product){
        $Url='';
        if(!is_null($Product->getData('name'))){
           $Url =. $Product->getData('name').'-';
        }

        if(!is_null($Product->getData('sku'))){
           $Url =. $Product->getData('sku');
        }

        Mage::log('My log entry'.$Url, null, 'mylogfile.log');
        $Product->setData('url_key', rtrim($Url, '-');      
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a try a little later and report back. For some reason when I update my URL keys, they aren't reflected. ie if the key is changed, the old url is still active, doesn't redirect and the new url doens't work.....

Comment: Got it working, turns out that it had to do with store views. Thanks for the help!