# Add/Edit Product - Append selected attribute value to product title

Tags: product, product-attribute, product-edit

I would like to Add selected attribute values to product title while adding/editing a product in admin.

eg. Product Name entered: Laptop

Attributes Selected
1) Brand - Toshiba
2) Colour- White
3) other attribute value

When a product added/edited from admin, the above selected attribute value concatenate to the title and then save in database.

Final Output: Product Name: Toshiba Laptop White (attribute sequence doesn't matter)

While writing this question: other issue, while editing product the attribute values saved in database will be shown in product name field. So while submitting the revised item, ideally it should check if product name contains attribute value if so ignore attribute values.

Basically, I want product name based on selected attributes values of a certain product.

By this, custom attributes are not required to manually add on places like catalog list/view, cart, invoices, pdf, email, customer account, breadcrumb, and other relative places.

[The other solution would be manually echo of attribute values on required locations (invoices, pdf, email, catalog and so on) which means editing lots of files which in opinion would be cumbersome!]

I am open to paid extension/work or customise code which could resolve this issue.

Please anyone who could help ?

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41447/recreating-url-keys

Comment: Is this in the admin add/edit product or when adding product to cart?

Comment: It's Admin add/edit.

Answer (score 2):

I have Create An Module For This Purpose.
It May be help full for you.

```
 app\etc\modules\Designo_Productname.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Designo_Productname>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Designo_Productname>
        </modules>
</config>

app\code\local\Designo\Productname\etc\config.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Designo_Productname>
             <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Designo_Productname>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <productname>
                <class>Designo_Productname_Helper</class>
            </productname>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
             <adminhtml>
                  <args>
                      <modules>
                          <Designo_Productname before="Mage_Adminhtml">Designo_Productname_Adminhtml</Designo_Productname>
                      </modules>
                 </args>
            </adminhtml>
         </routers>
     </admin>
  </config> 

 app\code\local\Designo\Productname\Helper\Data.php

<?php
 class Designo_Productname_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
 {
 }

app\code\local\Designo\Productname\controllers\Adminhtml\Catalog\ProductController.php

 <?php
 require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php';
 class Designo_Productname_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController
 {

 public function editAction()
 {
    $productId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $product = $this->_initProduct();
    $productName = $product->getData('name');
    Mage::register('previous_name',$productName);
    $productColor = $product->getAttributeText('color');
    $productBrand = $product->getAttributeText('computer_manufacturers');
    $ProductCompleteName = $productName.' '.$productBrand.' '.$productColor;

    $product->setData('name',$ProductCompleteName);
    if ($productId && !$product->getId()) {
        $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('This product no longer exists.'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }

    $this->_title($product->getName());

    Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_edit_action', array('product' => $product));

    $_additionalLayoutPart = '';
    if ($product->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE
        && !($product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductAttributeIds()))
    {
        $_additionalLayoutPart = '_new';
    }

    $this->loadLayout(array(
        'default',
        strtolower($this->getFullActionName()),
        'adminhtml_catalog_product_'.$product->getTypeId() . $_additionalLayoutPart
    ));

    $this->_setActiveMenu('catalog/products');

    if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode() && ($switchBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('store_switcher'))) {
        $switchBlock->setDefaultStoreName($this->__('Default Values'))
            ->setWebsiteIds($product->getWebsiteIds())
            ->setSwitchUrl(
                $this->getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, 'active_tab'=>null, 'tab' => null, 'store'=>null))
            );
    }

    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);

    $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.wysiwyg.js');
    if ($block) {
        $block->setStoreId($product->getStoreId());
    }

    $this->renderLayout();
}
/**
 * Save product action
 */
public function saveAction()
{
    $storeId        = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store');
    $redirectBack   = $this->getRequest()->getParam('back', false);
    $productId      = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $isEdit         = (int)($this->getRequest()->getParam('id') != null);

    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $data['name'] = Mage::registry('previous_name');
    if ($data) {
        $this->_filterStockData($data['product']['stock_data']);

        $product = $this->_initProductSave();

        try {
            $product->save();
            $productId = $product->getId();

            /**
             * Do copying data to stores
             */
            if (isset($data['copy_to_stores'])) {
                foreach ($data['copy_to_stores'] as $storeTo=>$storeFrom) {
                    $newProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->setStoreId($storeFrom)
                        ->load($productId)
                        ->setStoreId($storeTo)
                        ->save();
                }
            }

            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('The product has been saved.'));
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage())
                ->setProductData($data);
            $redirectBack = true;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            $redirectBack = true;
        }
    }

    if ($redirectBack) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array(
            'id'    => $productId,
            '_current'=>true
        ));
    } elseif($this->getRequest()->getParam('popup')) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/created', array(
            '_current'   => true,
            'id'         => $productId,
            'edit'       => $isEdit
        ));
    } else {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/', array('store'=>$storeId));
    }
}
```

}

Before Install this Module Create Backup of your site and Database. After Install this Module Flush All Cache.

It May be helpfull for you.

Comment: thanks for the post, I will try this. May I know what are the functionalities this module covers?

Comment: this is not working properly

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [Recreating URL keys](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41447/recreating-url-keys)

```
class MageStack_24869_Model_Observer{
  public function updateurl($observer){
    //Mage::log('My log entry', null, 'mylogfile.log');
    $_product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()
    if($_product){
        $name = '';
        $brand = $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer')
        if(strpos($_product->getData('name'), 'Brand') === false)){
           $name =. $_product->getData('name') . ' ' . $brand;
        }

        .....

        $Product->setData('name', rtrim($name, '-');      
    }
  }
}
```

You may want to create a new attribute to store the original product title to avoid do a lot of string manipulation

See [Customizing magento using event observer method](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)

Comment: thanks for the response. I didn't thought about url key, now I know they also need to be updated. Looking at this and recreating URL keys post they all are updating url keys. I wonder how would I update product name as well? I am not a magento expert, this is the first time I am working with magento. It would be much helpful if you could explain a little bit more!? thanks

Comment: Every time a product is save in magento it will trigger `catalog_product_save_before` event which can be catch using an observer. Therefore in your update  product attribute before it is save ... [read more](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)

Comment: above url not working

Comment: Just add the link to my answer ( Customizing magento using event observer method)

Comment: hi RS, The above method is bit complicated, when every time a product gets edited, it has to check if attribute value already added in title. Further, if we change attribute value it should first delete previous value added in product name then add new one. So, I would like to know what is the best way to add custom attribute appear along with product name on cart, invoices, pdf, almost every where. Any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If your only wish is to add the attributes to the title, why not changing the `page/html/head.phtml` or implement an observer which changes the title: `\Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::setTitle`